# Failure in template type resolution

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, variadic

This is driving me insane.  I just want to send a variadic list of pairs of strings into a template function that replaces words in a string, and the function works, but only with one parameter, not variadic.

This works fine

```
using std::string;
using spair = std::pair<string, string>;


string replace_all(string& str, const spair& sp)
 {
    string::size_type pos = 0;
    string::size_type rmsize = std::get<0>(sp).size();

  while((pos = str.find(std::get<0>(sp), pos)) != string::npos)
     {
        str.replace(pos, rmsize, std::get<1>(sp));
        pos++;
     }

  return str;

}

string pattern = "My name is {{first_name}} {{last_name}} and I live in {{location}}";

string t = replace_all( pattern,  {"{{first_name}}","Homer"}  );

/*************************/
```

But this will not work

```
template<typename T=spair, typename  ...Args>
string replace_all(string& s, const T& arg1,  Args const&... args )
{
   s = replace_all(s, arg1);
  
   s = replace_all(s, args...);

  return s;  
}

string v = replace_all( pattern,         
          {"{{first_name}}","Homer"},
          {"{{last_name}}","Simpson"}, 
          {"{{location}}","Springfield"} 
          );
```

variadic.cpp:72:8: error: no matching function for call to **‘replace_all(std::string&, <brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’

Comment: You are running into a fundamental weakness of variadic parameters. Braced initialization lists are typeless, and they cannot be bound to template parameters that call for a discrete type to be bound to. This is fundamental aspect of how templates work, and there are no clean solutions here. You'll either have to explicitly type each parameter, instead of providing a raw braced initialization list, or change the entire approach.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some abuse of initializer lists and templates here. To sum up:

- The internal type is known, it's always a pair of strings.
- The amount of "replace pairs" should be configurable

Using templates here, would force a new (function) type to be generated whenever `replace_all` is called with a different number of pairs. You can greatly simplify if you rely on "runtime lists" like so:

```cpp
string replace_all(string& s, std::vector<spair> const& v)
{
    for (auto const& sp : v) replace_all(s, sp);
    return s;  
}

// call it like so
replace_all(pattern, 
  {         
    {"{{first_name}}","Homer"},
    {"{{last_name}}","Simpson"}, 
    {"{{location}}","Springfield"} 
  }
) << std::endl;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b823cba420899ce)

As @Sam Varshavchik mentions in the comments, doing pattern matching with the method you suggest is a bit of a problem. It could work if you call your function like so:

```cpp
replace_all(pattern,        
    spair{"{{first_name}}","Homer"},
    spair{"{{last_name}}","Simpson"}, 
    spair{"{{location}}","Springfield"} 
);
```

thus making the type to be deduced explicit.

Comment: even lighter weight would be:

    string replace_all(string& s, std::initializer_list<spair> const& il)

I tried it and it works.

Comment: @ChrisReid [even even lighter](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d14dbf287f81392) would be to use an array `template <size_t N> string replace_all(string &s, spair const (&v)[N])` but I doubt you'll actually gain any performance out of such changes. I'd optimize for readability, all such variations are basically the same thing (only if you want to avoid the extra "includes" the array solution has an advantage)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it exactly, but I devised a workaround:

```
// 1 to 5 replacement pairs
const spair emptyspair{{},{}};  // A "nothing" pair of empty strings

string replace_all(string& s,
           const spair& sp1=emptyspair,
           const spair& sp2=emptyspair,
           const spair& sp3=emptyspair,
           const spair& sp4=emptyspair,
           const spair& sp5=emptyspair
           )
{
  
  std::array<spair,5> v{sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5};
  
  for (spair sp : v )
    {
      if (sp != emptyspair)
         {
            auto& s1 = std::get<0>(sp); 
            auto& s2 = std::get<1>(sp);
            s = replace_all(s, s1, s2);
         }
    }
  
  return s;
}
```

This allows 1 to 5 spair arguments, defaulting to a dummy pair
each that are ignored in the array that holds them.
I think that all references bind to the same default object
so do not cause 10 string objects and 5 pairs to be created,
and the inequality check compares quickly to  the same object.